# A pseudorandom number generator with a seed greater than 80 bits

Tags: random-generation, randomness

I need to generate a sequence of pseudorandom numbers with a period larger than $2^{80}$, using a seed larger than 80 bits, on a 32-bit embedded  microprocessor. What are my possible options (in terms of PRNGs), and which one is the fastest. The PRNG should pass the NIST 800-22 randomness tests.

Comment: Why does the seed have to be so large?  You can get PRNGs with longer periods that use small seeds.  See answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20141142/about-mersenne-twister-generators-period) for an explanation of how this works in the case of a Mersenne Twister.  (Note that you do have the option of seeding a Mersenne Twister with 624 32-bit numbers, but usually it will just generate that seed array from a 32-bit seed using a lower-quality PRNG.)  Concerning speed, Kneusel's book *Random Numbers and Computers* is useful.